# Finding when the order of the collection has changed in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app fetching a collection of posts from an API. I want to know when the order of the posts was changed in the backend and I thought I could do that with the [sort](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) event, but the strange thing is that I added a listener to that event in the view rendering the posts and I found that it's fired every time the collection is fetched, regardless of it the order of the posts changed or not.

I am missing something here?

Is there a way to check if the order of the collection has changed after fetch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are taking the wrong approach. You should order your collection in the client, regardless of what's the order returned by the server. The philosophy of Backbone, if I'm correct, is to manipulate a blob of JSON data on the client. Think of the server as your database/service layer, and use the ordering capabilities of collections in the client.

I didn't understand what you meant with 'order of the posts was changed in the backend'. If you want posts ordered by whatever field in your client app, use the collection comparator property.

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-comparator

Comment: The thing is that the order of the posts is given by users using another application. That is, there is an admin application where editors can write posts, update them and maybe update the order of the posts and there's the application I am working on that has to display the posts provided by the admin interface. I want to know if the order have changed to know that I have to re-render my view.

Comment: Hola Patricia. I would then try to get that sort information from the backend to Backbone and use it there, instead of trying to guess what happened. If the admin app updates the order, then that order must be stored somewhere. Is it a post field like 'DisplayOrder' or similar? Then sent that field to the client too, and listen for 'change' event on the models. If that sort field is changed, the change event will be raised.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! I added an 'order' field to post and make the view listen to 'change:order' events. I guess 'sort' event is only related to sorting on Backbone side.

Comment: Great to hear you had access to the server side part, too ;)